# Are all infinite-dimensional Lie groups noncompact?

Tags: gn.general-topology, lie-groups, compactness

Basically what the title says — if a Lie group is infinite-dimensional, is it necessarily noncompact?

Comment: I'm not sure the notion of infinite-dimensional Lie group is entirely standard, so you might want to provide the particular definition you are working with (or at least cite a reference with the precise definition).

Comment: @SamHopkins I suppose roughly the structure I am imagining is an infinite dimensional smooth manifold (in the sense of being locally homeomorphic to a Banach space) and endowed with a group structure. I am coming from physics rather than math so I imagine roughly that the most restrictive possible structure consistent with a nonempty set of interesting examples is appropriate, but I admit I don't have a perfectly precise notion of what should be in this category.

Comment: It's not locally compact, hence not compact.

Comment: What @YCor said.  An infinite-dimensional Banach space cannot be locally compact.